# Tags for woo "celebrities"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we allow/create tags for well known Woo-woos and snake-oil salesmen?

- [jenny-mccarthy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenny-mccarthy)
- [david-icke](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/david-icke)
- [jim-humble](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jim-humble)

Etc.

They all have a proven track record in unsubstantiated claims and being able to cross reference question would be useful.

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4983/38337

Answer (score 4):

I don't mind the idea of tagging names for commonly-mentioned notable people.

But we should be careful about saying that they are Woo-woos, because that is an ad hominem attack. Jenny McCarthy's *next* idea needs to be considered on its own merits.

Answer (score 1):

I think so. If they're very active, like Jenny McCarthy is, then there will be people who will want refutation of their newest arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There are notable pseudoscientists, who originate bogus theories, and there are notable celebrities, who make existing theories more popular. I think they're somewhat separate.

Answer (score -1):

#### 12 years later, none of these three tags have any questions, and none of the people associated with those tags have enough questions about them to warrant a tag of their own.

The three answers so far to this question, have focused on whether or not people like "pseudoscientists" deserve their own tag, but a more general discussion that also needs to be made is whether or not ***any*** individuals need to have their own tag (whether or not they are pseudoscientists), and that discussion has started here: [What are the criteria for having an entire tag just for one person?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4983/38337)