# [donald-trump], you're fired!

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Questions should not be tagged based on the claimant, i.e. the person or organisation making a claim.

It's not possible to have expertise on claims by a certain person. To be an expert on claims by Donald Trump, you'd have to know about [Mexican immigrants](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35596/in-the-us-are-illegal-immigrants-more-likely-to-commit-crimes), [Muslim immigrants](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34792/are-thousands-of-islamic-terrorists-entering-the-united-states) and the [Iranian government](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34867/did-iranians-kill-the-scientist-who-helped-the-us), not to being mention an expert on vaccination.

Likewise, to be an expert on the Daily Mail, you'd not only have to be an expert on immigration into the UK, but also on [oncology](http://kill-or-cure.herokuapp.com/).

Also, many claims are expressed by a variety of people. For example, Donald Trump and Robert De Niro have expressed similar claims about vaccination. We can't tag a question with everyone who's made a given claim or a similar version of it.

(Note: I'm not suggesting burninating [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump), as he's also the subject of numerous claims)

Previous questions:

- [Tags for woo "celebrities"?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/tags-for-woo-celebrities)
- [Should we allow "name" tags?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243/should-we-allow-name-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Creating a dr-mercola tag?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/creating-a-dr-mercola-tag?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Same goes for [mercola] and all the other tags that are just names of people.

Comment: +1 for the HNQ-bate title. +1 for the idea. Claim source is NOT really a valid thing to tag on (and this comes from CDO individual who loves tags so much he proposed hierarchical tag structure on Meta.SE and got into heavy discussions about not deleting useful tags on other sites :)

Comment: OCD (obsessive compulsive disorder), not CDO, and HNQ-bait (hot network question bait, like click-bait)

Comment: This question may need featuring at some point...

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4983/38337

Answer (score 16):

My first reaction to this was: we should use tags to help people to deliberately search for questions that interest them and to have serendipitous discoveries of other related questions. I have used the [joseph-mercola](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-mercola) tag, when I had vague memories that Mercola had made a similar claim. So, I didn't like your idea.

But, as I tried to marshall my argument, and re-read your post, I find you have a lot of good points.

In particular:

- The [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) is used for claims *about* Donald Trump and claims *by* Donald Trump, which seems clumsy.
- Many people can make the same claim. I'm pretty sure I have occasionally removed tags when people have tried to use them to make a partisan political point about someone being wrong, rather than find the truth about a claim.

I recognise this uncomfortable feeling of wanting to stutter "But... but... but..." in a discussion. It is the dawning realisation that my position is wrong. So I am writing this answer to reassure you that your suggestion was heard, and I am slowly adjusting my view (or coming up with a killer counter-point; whichever comes first.)

Comment: So can we edit all the questions tagged [tag:joseph-mercola]? From what I see, none are using the tag for claims about the person, but claims he's made. There's no reason for the tag to exist.

Comment: @fredsbend: Yes, good point.

Answer (score -1):

### Keep the tag!

---

Your argument is that:

> "It's not possible to have expertise on claims by a certain person. "

However, tags don't need to be designed based on ***expertise***. They can also be designed based on ***interest.*** People can "watch" tags, and even [subscribe to email notifications when a question is asked with a particular tag](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/59/5).

If enough people are interested in [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) to "watch" the tag or to subscribe to it, then the tag is worth keeping. I don't know if there is an easy way to find out how many subscribers a tag has, but 13 people are "watching" the [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) tag and with 184 questions so far, it is currently the 24th biggest tag on the entire site in terms of the number of questions (and it is still growing because he is running in the 2024 election).