# I do not like some uses of [Facebook]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some questions tagged with [facebook](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) are merely tagged that way because the claim is being spread via a Facebook meme or picture, such as [Is this a photo of a rough sleeper who froze to death?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40417/is-this-a-photo-of-a-rough-sleeper-who-froze-to-death) . As per the question [[donald-trump], you're fired!](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/donald-trump-youre-fired) should such usages be removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, facebook should be the object of questions tagged [facebook], not simply the media.

I fixed the wrong usages