# Should we evolve out of the tags [intelligent-design] and [young-earth-creationism]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Currently we have the tags [young-earth-creationism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-earth-creationism) and [intelligent-design](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligent-design). The questions aren’t used for questions that are about those movements, but to categorise claims that are made by those movements. Should we get rid of these tags as per the logic of [[donald-trump], you're fired!](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/donald-trump-youre-fired) ?

Comment: I don't think that the comparison to that Donald Trump tag is fair here.  That meta discussion is saying not to use the tag solely because Donald Trump asked a question.  The tag isn't being applied as a "young Earth Creation_ist_" tag; it's being used when the topic of the question is young Earth creationism.  Questions about Donald Trump still can use his tag; which is the same context that these two tags are used in as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

I think not: a claim that the Earth is young is (by definition) [young-earth-creationism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-earth-creationism). People who believe that the Earth is young are young Earth creationists, not matter whether they are part of any official movement.

Same for intelligent design, it's a subject of claims, not a movement.

Comment: I'll try to see if the same logic exists for other questions on the site, but I may take a while to do so.