# Is it appropriate to tag questions with "sovereign-citizens" or "OPCA"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[OPCA (Organized Pseudolegal Commercial Arguments)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPCA) is a family of legal conspiracy theories, chiefly about avoiding paying tax. Sovereign Citizens are the most well known movement. Would it be appropriate to tag questions such as these with [sovereign-citizens](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sovereign-citizens) or [opca](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opca)? Alternatively, these questions could be tagged as [tax protester arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_protester_arguments). (Sovereign citizen arguments go beyond taxes, with some claiming not to be subject to many laws. A few have killed law enforcement officers.)

Applicable questions:

- [Are US workers legally required to pay income taxes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/42662/21255)
- [Has income tax been found unconstitutional by a court?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/18474/21255)
- [Have any Freeman of the land applications been successful in court?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/30970/21255)
- [Are American courts and federal agencies foreign-controlled private corporations?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/31451/21255)
- [Have local/state common law courts been replaced with federal martial/maritime courts in the US?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/31455/21255)
- [Are the ABA and IRS foreign-owned private debt collection agencies?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/31456/21255)
- [Are those born in the US considered non-citizen wards of the state and/or corporations?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/31457/21255)
- [Can I avoid property tax by showing a judge my land grant?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/35715/21255)
- [Was the 16th Amendment (income tax) improperly ratified?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13558/21255)

Personally, it makes sense to me to have a specific tag for this category of legal argument, rather than the very broad [law](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) or [taxes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) tags.

Comment: I'm honestly not even seeing the distinction between the two.

Answer (score -1):

We decided a long time ago not to use meta tags and tags that refer to the "type" of question. [opca](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opca) is certainly such at tag and I've removed it. Please do not use it anymore.

There are no questions tagged [sovreign-citizen](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sovreign-citizen) and in any case I have no idea on why would that constitute a good tag.

Comment: What? These aren't meta tags, they're tags about economic conspiracy theories.

Comment: If young-earth-creationism is a valid tag then so should be sovereign-citizens. Neither are about the type of question, but are about a specific belief system. (And the reason there were no questions tagged sovereign-citizens before was because they were all tagged opca.)

Comment: Though after looking through the list of tags, I didn't see very many tags for specific conspiracy theories or pseudo-sciences etc. Is that what you meant? That wouldn't be considered a "meta tag" elsewhere on the network (which are things "homework" and "soft-question"), but I can understand not wanting them. In that case will you remove the young-earth-creationism tag too? Lastly, just for future people, do you have a link to where it was decided these tags shouldn't be used?

Comment: @curiousdannii well, YEC is an objective characteristic of a question, whereas "pseudoscience" is something that can only be determined by answering a question. It's like tagging something "homeopathy", which is not in doubt, instead of "pseudoscience". Regarding "sovreign-citizen": no question is tagged that way

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what the problem with sovereign-citizens is? It's specific, like YEC and homeopathy, not broad like pseudoscience. Would you be okay with me tagging the questions listed about with sovereign-citizens?

Comment: Supporting Sklivvz's view, note that OPCA is a declaration that the legal claim is false (the P stands for Pseudolegal). That doesn't belong on a *question*. It belongs on an *answer*, but this site doesn't have answer tags.

Comment: @curiousdannii FWIW there's a discussion about young-earth-creationism at https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/should-we-evolve-out-of-the-tags-intelligent-design-and-young-earth-creationi

Comment: I'm not sure these would be  tags we should have, but they certainly aren't meta tags.

Comment: @fredsbend https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/too-broad-tags-like-science-and-pseudo-science

Comment: @sklivvz I know what a meta tag is and these aren't like that.

Comment: So your idea is that "pseudolegal argument" is not a meta tag and "pseudoscience" is? OK, well

Comment: Nobody suggested "pseudolegal argument" as a tag. If what @curious says is accurate, these suggested tags represent a school of thought, not a single (pseudo-x) idea.

Comment: But that still doesn't mean they should be tags here. I've never heard of these things.

Comment: context: the "P" and the "A" on OPCA are, in fact, "pseudolegal" and "argument", which is why I'm saying it's like "pseudoscience"

Comment: @sklivvz From wikipedia OPCA is a "term used by some judges and legal scholars to refer to arguments used in litigation related to" some specific movements. It is pseudolaw, but only in the same way YEC is pseudoscience. Please make sure to ping me if you reply.

Comment: @fredsbend sorry about the ping. As Wikipedia also notices, calling something an OPCA is akin to calling something a conspiracy theory. We don't allow that tag either (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_protester_conspiracy_arguments)