# Can we add to tagging instructions not to tag on claimant?

Tags: feature-request, tagging

Is it possible, in the instructions for tagging, to state that tagging ought to be on the *subject* of the claim, rather than on the *claimant*?

> [image: Graphic showing location of text]

It’s understandable that the average user won’t browse meta about how to tag, but there’s a reasonable chance, at least amongst diligent users, to read instructions about tagging.

Today, someone used the tag “planned parenthood” to tag a claim by Planned Parenthood, rather than a claim about the organisation.

Comment: Rejected question title: “Donald Trump style tagging still going on? Sad!”

Comment: Which instructions are you referring to?

Comment: @Oddthinking the instructions that go “How to tag” “A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Choose one or more (up to 5) tags that will help answerers to find and interpret your question. ...”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text isn't under the control of mods, so it is not something I can action.

It would require special "per-site" coding or configuration from the SE team - they should see this request here.

Similar requests tend to be prioritised low, unfortunately.

[This isn't a "rejection" answer - it is just explaining why the mods haven't responded to the request.]

---

I know we have discussed the issue before: Here is the post where you convinced me of this approach: [[donald-trump], you're fired!](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/donald-trump-youre-fired)

However, I can't see that we ever made a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question/answer on the topic. That should be the first step. Given you are a proponent, would you like to draft a [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) question/answer?

Comment: Yeah, I was half expecting that mods can’t change that info. I’ll write up a proposed FAQ in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I don't think is configurable at all, it's all text in the Razor template IIRC.