# What are the criteria for having an entire tag just for one person?

Tags: discussion, politics, tagging, retagging

Whenever I see a tag that is used for ***only one question***, it catches my eye. Recently I noticed that [benjamin-netanyahu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benjamin-netanyahu) was only used for one question, namely: [Did Netanyahu recently say "We will turn Gaza into a deserted island"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/56101/38337) I proposed to remove the tag, since it's single-use tags are generally frowned upon, but my edit [was not able to be reviewed by the wider community since the OP single-handedly rejected it](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44291). The OP then added the tag to this question from 2018: [Did Netanyahu's recent presentation on Iran's nuclear program contain no new information?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/41211/38337) and this extremely downvoted question from 2017 that was closed as "off-topic": [Did Benjamin Netanyahu say this about Christian Zionists?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/36702/38337), so there's now a total of 3 questions with the [benjamin-netanyahu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benjamin-netanyahu) tag.

Before asking this question on Meta, I did some research on how such tags are used on the rest of the site. As a general rule of thumb, when a tag has 100 or more questions, it is ***eligible*** for a lot of things (e.g. even if you have a total score of 1,000,000 across 90 answers with a tag, you will not even get the bronze badge for that tag because tags need to have at least 100 questions to become eligible for badges; also consideration for the generalist badge requires tags to have at least 100 questions). If a tag is unlikely ever to reach 100 questions, it means that badges will not be awarded for that tag, and therefore the tags relevance for moderation purposes (people with gold badges on a tag have moderation powers for questions with that tag, which allows us to have several more moderators for some of the busier tags, for example), but the tags might still be useful for non-moderation purposes (e.g. people can "watch" a tag if they're interested in it).

[israel](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) has only 62 questions (this will become relevant in the next paragraphs), and despite [ukraine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukraine) being such a hot topic since 2014 (and even hotter since early 2022), there's currently only 52 questions with that tag.

In terms of tags for ***individual*** people, despite [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) having 1509 questions:

- [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) has only 184 questions,
- [barrack-obama](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barrack-obama) has only 65 questions, and
- [joe-biden](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joe-biden) has only 21 questions.

If the tag [israel](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) quadruples in size to have 248 question within the next few years, and if [benjamin-netanyahu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benjamin-netanyahu) gets just as many question compared to the size of [israel](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) as [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) got compared to the size of [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), then [benjamin-netanyahu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benjamin-netanyahu) would still be a minor tag (even more minor if we use [barack-obama](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barack-obama) or [joe-biden](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joe-biden) as the benchmark rather than [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump)) without most of the features of tags, and questions with his tag could probably be tagged equally well with just the [israel](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) tag.

Anyway, the following is a list of some of the other tags that we have for ***individual*** people.

#### **Politicians/leaders**

- [hilary-clinton](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hilary-clinton) has only 35 questions,
- [adolf-hitler](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adolf-hitler) has only 34 questions,
- [vladimir-putin](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vladimir-putin) has only 15 questions,
- [bernie-sanders](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bernie-sanders) has only 12 questions,
- [osama-bin-laden](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osama-bin-laden) has only 11 questions,
- [jfk](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jfk) has only 10 questions,
- [winston-churchill](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winston-churchill) has only 10 questions,
- [nelson-mandela](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nelson-mandela) has only 9 questions,
- [gaddafi](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaddafi) has only 6 questions,
- [al-gore](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/al-gore) has only 6 questions,
- [george-washingont](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-washingont) has only 5 questions,
- [fidel-castro](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fidel-castro) has only 4 questions,
- [genghis-khan](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genghis-khan) has only 4 questions,
- [bill-clinton](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bill-clinton) has only 3 questions,
- [amin-al-husseini](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amin-al-husseini) has only 3 questions,
- [tony-abbott](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tony-abbott) has only 3 questions,
- [boris-johnson](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boris-johnson) has only 2 questions, despite [united-kingdom](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) having only 185 tags.
- [michael-bloomberg](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/michael-bloomberg) has only 2 questions
- [joseph-geobbels](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-geobbels) has only 2 questions

#### **Academics/researchers/writers/inventors**

- [albert-einstein](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/albert-einstein) has only 41 questions,
- [thomas-edison](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thomas-edison) has only 8 questions,
- [nikola-tesla](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikola-tesla) has only 7 questions,
- [william-shakespeare](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare) has only 7 questions,
- [leonardo-da-vinci](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leonardo-da-vinci) has only 6 questions,
- [charles-darwin](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charles-darwin) has only 5 questions,
- [alan-turing](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alan-turing) has only 5 questions,
- [carl-sagan](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carl-sagan) has only 3 questions,
- [richard-dawkins](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/richard-dawkins) has only 3 questions,
- [andrew-wakefield](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/andrew-wakefield) has only 3 questions,
- [david-graeber](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/david-graeber) has only 3 questions.

#### **Television personalities**

- [mehmet-oz](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mehmet-oz) has only 8 questions,
- [bruce-lee](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bruce-lee) has only 3 questions (one of them has the [celebrities](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celebrities) tag),
- [charlie-chaplin](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charlie-chaplin) has only 3 questions,
- [leonardo-dicaprio](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leonardo-dicaprio) has only 1 question.

#### Others, or people that strongly fall into more than one of the above categories

- [jesus-christ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus-christ) has only 20 questions,
- [mahatma-gandhi](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahatma-gandhi) has only 13 questions,
- [julian-assange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julian-assange) has only 7 questions,
- [bill-gates](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bill-gates) has only 6 questions,
- [jeffrey-epstein](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jeffrey-epstein) has only 3 questions.

#### It seems clear that apart from [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump), no tag for an ***individual*** will reach 100 questions for several more years.

Other tags like [barrack-obama](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barrack-obama) are probably worth keeping because enough people "watch" the tag, but [leonardo-dicaprio](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leonardo-dicaprio) is currently only being usd in 1 question, and could easily be tagged with [celebrities](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celebrities) instead (along with all other actors, television personalities, and even the celebrity academics like [carl-sagan](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carl-sagan) about whom only 3 questions have been asked so far).

## My question:

Where shall we draw the line to decide whether or not to have a tag for an ***individual*** person?

Some related questions in the past were:

- [Should we allow "name" tags?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/243/38337)
- [[donald-trump], you're fired!](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3757/38337)
- [Tags for woo "celebrities"?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19/38337)
- [Creating a dr-mercola tag?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1274/38337)

Answer (score 4):

My reaction to this question is "What harm is it causing?" Perhaps I am missing something, so I remain open to further explanation.

We don't have the reach of Stack Overflow, so a vast majority of our tags will never reach the 100 questions mark. And that's okay.

People will never be able to get a badge for their [thomas-edison](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thomas-edison) expertise.  And that's okay.

Meanwhile, if someone is interested in [nikola-tesla](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikola-tesla) and the mythos built around him, if they find one question they will be led to the others. That seems a good thing.

So, I guess the line I would propose is "There is only one question, and it isn't likely that more will be added in the short term."

The [benjamin-netanyahu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benjamin-netanyahu) tag was only added when there were three questions. Seems reasonable.

[leonardo-dicaprio](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leonardo-dicaprio) is the only one in your list that I think should be considered for removal.

---

As the meta-questions point out, we now avoid tagging the *claimant*: the claim is true or false no matter who said it. We tag claims *about* a person, not *by* a person. I am not 100% sure this rule leads to the best user-experience, but that is what the community seems to have settled on.

For those unaware: Tags require 300 rep to create, so help a newbie out if they haven't added one. If a tag is removed from all its questions, the tag itself is deleted within 24 hours.

Comment: So your suggestion is that if the tag is likely to have 2 or more questions in the short-term, it is kept?

Comment: @user1271772: Yes, that's a fair summary

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious why the line would be drawn at 2 questions rather than at 1 question?

Comment: @user1271772: Because if a tag is only relevant to one question, it doesn't offer any "discoverability" for other questions. A person interested in the subject isn't going to get anything interesting making it a useless and annoying click. (This is just one opinion; I remain open to others.)